# Elantech touchpad multitouch sensitivity

Tags: touchpad

Is it possible to increase multitouch sensitivity? My Elantech touchpad has trouble noticing a 2 finger scroll unless I lay my hand flat and use a large area of my finger pads. Single touch is working just fine, though. I'm running a Manjaro  Xfce system in a Lenovo Edge 15 that was originally installed on an HP G72 and everything is working fine except the Elantech multitouch, which does work but is driving me nuts.